# Test that should throw an exception when specified file doesn't exist

Tags: java, junit

Hi I have a problem like this. My class is parsing input data and it should throw an exception when specified file doesn't exist. What is the correct way to do this? I have done something like this:

```
@Test
public void allOK() throws IOException {

    words = folder.newFile("words");

    String[] args = new String[10];
    args[0] = "-rw";
    args[1] = "20";
    args[2] = "-rf";
    args[3] = "4";
    args[4] = "-w";
    args[5] = "words";
    args[6] = "-r";
    args[7] = "results";
    args[8] = "-c";
    args[9] = "1000";

    Options options = Options.getInstance();

    options.setOptions(args);

    assertEquals(20, options.getRows());

}
```

Of course the folder is TemporaryFolder. I don't think I can send a temporary created file string to function. So the test always fails because file is not found. So can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely CAN send a temporary file to a "function". I suggest that you need to send the entire file path instead of just `words` since each time the test is run the file will be located in a new temp folder. Like `args[5] = words.getAbsolutePath();`